# selecting min from joined tables

Tags: sql, join, group-by, min

I can't figure this question out by myself so I am wondering if you guys could help me. I tried to find my answer on google, stackoverflow ans several other locations but without any result..

I made a query:

```
SELECT leverancier.leveranciers_id,
    medicijn.artikelnr,
    medicijn.naam,
    medicijn.in_voorraad,
    medicijn.min_voorraad,
    min(order_medicijn.inkoopprijs) AS price
FROM leverancier
INNER JOIN voorraadorder
    ON leverancier.leveranciers_id = voorraadorder.leverancier_id
INNER JOIN order_medicijn
    ON order_medicijn.voorraadorder_id = voorraadorder.voorraadorder_id
INNER JOIN medicijn
    ON medicijn.artikelnr = order_medicijn.artikel_id
GROUP BY leverancier.leveranciers_id,
    medicijn.artikelnr,
    medicijn.naam,
    medicijn.in_voorraad,
    medicijn.min_voorraad
ORDER BY artikelnr
```

Which gives the following result:

---

```
Leveranciers_ID / artikelnr / naam in_voorraad / min_voorraad / price

2   1   Aspirine       100  50  0.74
1   1   Aspirine       100  50  0.75
2   2   Abacivr        200  180 4.50
4   2   Abacivr        200  180 4.00
4   3   Acetazolamide  100  90  1.20
5   4   Ciclovir       145  120 0.50
3   5   levoceterizine 125  120 2.00
```

Here comes the question:
What query would I need to get the same result but only with the records where the price is the lowest for each artikelnr. So the result would be like this:

Leveranciers_ID / artikelnr / naam in_voorraad / min_voorraad / price

```
2   1   Aspirine       100  50  0.74


4   2   Abacivr        200  180 4.00
4   3   Acetazolamide  100  90  1.20
5   4   Ciclovir       145  120 0.50
3   5   levoceterizine 125  120 2.00
```

If there is any additional information required to answer this question, please ask me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the RDBMS that you are using?

Comment: I actually use 2 RDBMSystems. I use MySQLWorkbench and to edit some values I use PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Remove the aggregation(min()) and group by from your query and try the following:`select * from ...inner join....` and add a where clause at the end: `Where order_medicijn.inkoopprijs= (select min(t2.inkoopprijs) from order_medicijn t2 where t2.artikel_id=medicijn.artikelnr)`

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions: Adding one more inner SQL that computes the **min** price of each **artikelnr** and using the **HAVING** clause, which uses the inner SQL, to filter the result.

Cheers